# .NET CLR Performance counters missing

Tags: windows, clr

on my x64 Windows 8.1 laptop almost all .NET CLR performance counters are missing.

Any ideas how to fix this?

[image: .NET Counters missing]

Comment: This is a pretty unhealthy kind of problem to have, it points at registry or disk corruption.  The counters are registered at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\.NETFramework\Performance and involve several files that need to be present.  One of which is C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework\corperfmonsymbols.ini, it names the counters.  Best to give your machine a thorough health-check first, reinstall .NET next.  Ask for advice at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks for the info. After some researching I've reach out the file location that you've pointed out then i ran  `lodctr C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework\corperfmonsymbols.ini` on command prompt - woila! CLR Counters reappeared

Comment: Don't ignore the registry damage.

Comment: Note that it may matter if you run the 32-bit or 64-bit lodctr.exe.
For me, it required the 32-bit to restore the counters, even on a 64-bit OS

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**lodctr** did the trick but the file *corperfmonsymbols.ini* was in

> C:\Windows\Inf.NETFramework

not in the

> %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework*

directories.

Command `lodctr C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework\corperfmonsymbols.ini` successfully restored .NET CLR counters.

Comment: This isn't working for me, did you have to restart the machine?

Comment: Yes restart was required as far as I can remember.

Comment: The counters appeared in Performance Counter without a restart.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to follow these steps which are given by [MSDN](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306722):

> To resolve this problem, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Ensure that the RTM build is installed on the computer through the  Microsoft .NET Software Development Kit (SDK) setup, .NET Redist, or
>      Visual  Studio .NET.
> 2. At a command prompt, type unlodctr .NETFramework.
> 3. At a command prompt, type lodctr
>
>    %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705\CORPerfMonSymbols.ini.

Also check this [blog for reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikedodd/archive/2004/10/17/243799.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the input. **lodctr** did the trick but the file was in `C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework` ,not in the `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\*` directories.